# Golang embedded structures

Tags: go

I am a little confused with a behavior of Go regarding variable 'overriding' in embedded structure.

**First situation**
If a `child` structure embeds a `parent` structure containing a field `Attr`, I can access the value of Attr indifferently with `child.Attr` or `child.parent.Attr`. Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/-E0tI99UVBx) :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type parent struct {
    Attr    int `json:"attr"`
}

type child struct {
    parent
}

func main() {
    var c child
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"i": 1}`), &c)
    fmt.Println(c.Attr)
    fmt.Println(c.parent.Attr)
}
```

**Second situation**
However, if the child structure contains itself a field named `Attr`, those two fields are different and can be accessed separately, as shows the following [example](https://play.golang.org/p/TzCB6WT-L2A) :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type parent struct {
    Attr    int `json:"attr"`
}

type child struct {
    parent
    Attr    int
}

func main() {
    var c child
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"attr": 1}`), &c)
    fmt.Println(c.Attr)
    fmt.Println(c.parent.Attr)
}
```

I am very surprised that this implicit behavior is allowed in golang. I would have expected the language to be stricter as it is on so many points. Besides, I wasn't able to find a clear specification about this. Is it just a side-effect or can I use that feature?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors

Comment: Woh yes thank you @Volker! how did I miss that... You can make it an answer if you want so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Golang specification actually states how embedded fields are resolved

> A selector f may denote a field or method f of a type T, or it may
>   refer to a field or method f of a nested embedded field of T. The
>   number of embedded fields traversed to reach f is called its depth in
>   T. The depth of a field or method f declared in T is zero. The depth
>   of a field or method f declared in an embedded field A in T is the
>   depth of f in A plus one.

Then...

> For a value x of type T or *T where T is not a pointer or interface
>   type, x.f denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in T
>   where there is such an f. If there is not exactly one f with
>   shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.